# Parse a list of attribute/values in PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing

Given a string with attribute/value pairs such as

```
attr1="some text" attr2 = "some other text" attr3= "some weird !@'#$\"=+ text"
```

the goal is to parse it and output an associative array, in this case:

```
array('attr1' => 'some text',
      'attr2' => 'some other text',
      'attr3' => 'some weird !@\'#$\"=+ text')
```

Note the inconsistent spacing around the equal signs, the escaped double quote in the input, and the escaped single quote in the output.

Comment: You're not parsing a markup language, right?

Comment: Good to ask that!  No, just making up my own syntax to be easy to type on a command line.

Comment: "to be easy to type on a command line", then you might be interested in http://docs.php.net/getopt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$text = "attr1=\"some text\" attr2 = \"some other text\" attr3= \"some weird !@'#$\\\"=+ text\"";
echo $text;
preg_match_all('/(\S+)\s*=\s*"((?:\\\\.|[^\\"])*)"/', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

which produces:

```
attr1="some text" attr2 = "some other text" attr3= "some weird !@'#$\"=+ text"

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => attr1="some text"
            [1] => attr1
            [2] => some text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => attr2 = "some other text"
            [1] => attr2
            [2] => some other text
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => attr3= "some weird !@'#$\"=+ text"
            [1] => attr3
            [2] => some weird !@'#$\"=+ text
        )

)
```

And a short explanation:

```
(\S+)               // match one or more characters other than white space characters
                    // > and store it in group 1
\s*=\s*             // match a '=' surrounded by zero or more white space characters 
"                   // match a double quote
(                   // open group 2
  (?:\\\\.|[^\\"])* //   match zero or more sub strings that are either a backslash
                    //   > followed by any character, or any character other than a
                    //   > backslash
)                   // close group 2
"                   // match a double quote
```

Comment: What about the third example?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to double escape the backslash (and double check the output). I'm afraid I am sometimes too confident in myself. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any difference between the way php and actionscript, that is ecmascript/js btw, handles regex? Because this regex gave only the first two attrs in actionscript.

Comment: Next to no experience in ECMA-ish regex flavours, but you might want to try `var regex = /(\S+)\s*=\s*"((?:\\.|[^\\"])*)"/g;`, or even `var regex = /(\S+)\s*=\s*"((?:\\.|[^\"])*)"/g;` (not tested!).

Comment: Both works well with all three cases given by OP, but not with a trailing backslash :(

Comment: A quick JS test produced the desired result with a (quoted) trailing backslash: `document.write("attr4=\"\\\\\"".match(/(\S+)\s*=\s*"((?:\\.|[^\\"])*)"/i));`

Comment: Thanks so much, Bart!  Is it much of a monkey wrench if I want the quotes to be optional in the case that the value has no spaces?

Comment: You're welcome Dreeves. No, it shouldn't be much hassle to include that. Try: `(\S+)\s*=\s*([^"\s]+|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*")`. If you need clarification, just say so and I'll include a brief explanation in my original post.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This regex fails if the value ends in a backslash like `attr4="something\\"`

I don't know PHP, but since the regex would be essentially the same in any language, this is how I did it in ActionScript:

```
var text:String = "attr1=\"some text\" attr2 = \"some other text\" attr3= \"some weird !@'#$\\\"=+ text\"";

var regex:RegExp = /\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(?:"(.*?)(?<!\\)")\s*/g;

var result:Object;
while(result = regex.exec(text))
    trace(result[1] + " is " + result[2]);
```

And I got the following out put:

> attr1 is some text
>   attr2 is some other text
>   attr3 is some weird !@'#$\"=+ text

Comment: Just a small nitpick: if the value contains a backslash itself, like `attr3 = "\\"` (which will likely need escaping too), it won't work with a negative look behind. Of course, that might never happen, the OP didn't mention such corner cases.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. And that's not a nitpick - apparently this fails if the string ends with a backslash - like `attr4="something\\"`