# Matching key=“value” pattern in PHP string

Tags: php, regex, parsing

How (easiest way) to convert a string like

```
oneKey="value 1" key2="value 2" anotherKey="value 3" somekey="value containing spaces"
```

to an array with PHP (regex or not)?

I would like to retreive the values like this :

```
$myArray['key']
```

so

```
$myArray['oneKey'] == "value"
```

**All keys are different**

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried so that we can provide a specific response that will be helpful in your situation.

Comment: I hope you're not trying to parse HTML attributes...

Comment: all keys are same? is 'key' the keyword used here?

Comment: @RaheelHasan No the keys are all different. I have updated the question. Thanks

Comment: This has been asked and answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605606/parse-a-list-of-attribute-values-in-php

Comment: @Kolink It has nothing to do with html but thanks...

Comment: @GeorgeCummins This is my first steps (and I hope the last) in PHP so sorry but I don't have a clue where to start from...

Comment: @xert Thanks... I tried hard to find this question but it looks like I was not searching for the correct terms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matching quoted strings is always tricky.

Assuming your data never contains an escaped double quote (i.e. a double quote that is part of the actual value, a simple

```
/(?<=^|\s)([^=]+)="([^"]*)"/
```

...would probably do the job, but it's unlikely that would be the case. So we need to get a little more complex than that, and that's where Friedl's classic "unrolled loop" comes to the rescue:

```
/(?<=^|\s)([^=\s]+)="((?:[^\\"]|\\.)*)"/
```

How does it work? Well, let's break it down:

First we start with a lookbehind to validate that the start of the match is preceded by either the start of the string or a whitespace character:

```
(?<=^|\s)
```

Next we look for any combination of non-whitespace and non-equals sign characters (at least 1 of them). This is the key, so we put it in a capture group:

```
([^=\s]+)
```

Next we have a literal equals sign and double quote:

```
="
```

Next it's the "unrolled loop". This can be a little difficult to follow at first, but it works by looking for any character that is not the a quote character or an escape character (I have chosen backslash as the escape character but really you can use anything), *or* an escape character followed by any other character. This is repeated zero or more times. Since this is the value, we wrap it in a capture group:

```
((?:[^\\"]|\\.)*)
```

Then we simply close with a literal double quote:

```
"
```

Put it all together into PHP code and you get something like this:

```
$subject = 'key1="value 1" key2="value 2" key3="value 3" key4="value containing spaces"';

$expr = '/(?<=^|\\s)([^=\\s]+)="((?:[^\\\\"]|\\\\.)*)"/';
preg_match_all($expr, $subject, $matches);

$result = array();
foreach ($matches[1] as $i => $key) {
    $result[$key] = $matches[2][$i];
}
```

[See it working](http://eval.in/17286)

---

But there's a small issue with this. Consider [what happens](http://eval.in/17287) when the subject string is:

```
key1="value\" 1"
```

Should be nice and simple, that's just an escaped quote, right? Well, that's true, the above expression can easily handle this case. But look at the output:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value\" 1
)
```

The escape character is still in the result string as a literal. This is not what we wanted. But the above expression only extracts the relevant components from the subject string, it doesn't interpollate them at all. For that we will need a separate process - but it's now just a simple search and replace, because we've already broken the string up into the tokens we want.

So we just do something like this:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\./', function($match) {
    switch ($match[0][1]) { // inspect the second character
        // here we can define our special escape sequences, for example:
        case 'r': return "\r";
        case 'n': return "\n";

        // For anything that we don't handle as a special case, we just return
        // the second character in the match, effectively strip the escape
        default: return $match[0][1];
    }
}, $subject);
```

So when you put that together with the above code, you get a something more like this:

```
$subject = 'key1="value \" 1" key2="value \n 2" key3="value 3" key4="value containing spaces"';

$matchExpr = '/(?<=^|\\s)([^=\\s]+)="((?:[^\\\\"]|\\\\.)*)"/';
$replaceExpr = '/\\\\./';

$replaceCallback = function($match) {
    switch ($match[0][1]) {
        case 'r': return "\r";
        case 'n': return "\n";
        default: return $match[0][1];
    }
};

preg_match_all($matchExpr, $subject, $matches);

$result = array();
foreach ($matches[1] as $i => $key) {
    $result[$key] = preg_replace_callback($replaceExpr, $replaceCallback, $matches[2][$i]);
}
```

[See it working](http://eval.in/17290)

Answer (score 0):

try this regex with **preg_match_all**:

```
/(key[0-9]{0,})\="(.+?)"/ims
```

and returned matches will have keys and values

Comment: what about `key11`,`key100`

Comment: `key[0-9]+` or `key\d+` would be better

Comment: really? then what about `key` without any number? (as per his original question).

Comment: anyway, I always prefer `{0,}` instead of `*` for groups (lets say, this is how I roll :D)

Answer (score -2):

```
$func = function($string) { $kv = preg_split(/="/, $string); $kv[1] = substr($kv[1], 0, length($kv[1]-1])); $myArray[$kv[0]] = $kv[1]; };
array_map($func, preg_split(/[[:space:]]+/, $string));
```